# "Do Not Track (DNT)" default settings for IE 9, IE 10, IE 11, other browsers?

Tags: browser, http-headers, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

What is the current state of browser (client side) support of "Do Not Track" HTTP header for IE 9, IE 10, IE 11, other browsers?

Comment: I don't believe the default settings were ever fully (or carefully) documented, though there are a few articles that might contain hints.  I do know that defaults can (and have) change(d) through the update process, so any documentation would need to be confirmed through research.  In any event, you're probably better off presuming the possibility that it's been enabled and design accordingly.  (Most sites appear to ignore the header.)  Further reading includes http://bit.ly/1BSLApq, http://bit.ly/1x3Tero, and http://bit.ly/1A6REWJ.

Comment: I've been puzzling IE11 defaults. I didn't see anything about "express settings" on your link there now. But I see it mentioned in this interesting wikipedia snippet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Not_Track#Internet_Explorer_10_default_setting_controversy . It seems the default was "on" for express settings on windows 10, but flip-flopped back to "off" again in later windows versions. A win 7 enterprise VM seems to have it "on" out of the box. Also I imagine this is commonly set "on" in office-wide intranet auto-installations. Long story short: IE11 has mixture of defaults

Comment: Thanks for your comment @HarryWood! I think you should post it as answer. I personally am not really interested in this topic anymore so I don't want to work on keeping my answer up to date. I just changed the links to use the Wayback Machine so they show the state as of March 2015.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research done in March 2015:

- DNT setting was introduced but **disabled** [by default](http://www.informationweek.com/applications/microsoft-adds-do-not-track-to-ie9/d/d-id/1096696?) in IE 9,
- it was NOT documented if it was enabled or disabled [by default](https://web.archive.org/web/20150320092722/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie-do-not-track#ie=ie-10) for IE 10,
- it was **enabled** [when using "express settings"](https://web.archive.org/web/20150320092722/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie-do-not-track#ie=ie-11) for IE 11:

"Do Not Track is turned on in Internet Explorer if you chose to use express settings when setting up your PC"

- is available but **disabled** by default in modern versions of Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

## Update 1

I tested how browserstack.com does it and apparently it does it differently than I described it above.

DNT is:

- disabled on IE 10 on Windows 8,
- disabled on IE 10 metro on Windows 8,
- disabled on IE 11 on Windows 8.1,
- disabled on IE 11 on Windows 7,
- enabled on IE 10 on Windows 7.

..but are these the real default settings?

### Update 2

Apparently they are not as Browserstack replied to my support request as follows:

> I checked on a fresh install of Windows 8-IE 10 and IE 11, and “Do Not Track” header is enabled by default. We will ensure the same setting is available on BrowserStack (...)